# Why is my custom filter not working in angular, and also the text is not appearing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-frontend, web-frameworks

I have just started learning Angular.js and came across the concept of custom filters. I tried creating one, but it didn't work. In fact, the text that was supposed to be filtered was also not displayed, though the console does not show any errors.

**let me show you my html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>learn angular</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Ashish toppo">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"> <!-- let us load our css file -->
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- let us load our angular.js file -->
    <script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script> <!-- let us load our js file -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="heading" id="heading"> {{"Hii"+" "+"There"}} </div>

    <!-- the below shall display the user data --> 
    <div ng-controller="userDataCtrl">
        <strong>First Name:</strong> {{data.firstName}} <span>(this is not filtered)</span> <br>
        <strong>Last Name:</strong> {{data.lastName}} <span>(this is not filtered)</span> <br>

        <hr>

        <strong>First Name:</strong> {{data.firstName | uppercase}}
        <span>(this is filtered to uppercase)</span> <br> 
        <strong>Last Name:</strong> {{data.lastName | lowercase}}
        <span>(this is filtered to lowercase)</span> <br>

        <hr>

        <strong>plan:</strong> {{data.plan | dashed}} <span>(this is custom filtered to Dashed)</span> 
        <br>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Now this is how my javaScript code goes like:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("userDataCtrl", function($scope){
    var userData = {
        firstName: "Ashish",
        middleName: "",
        lastName: "Toppo",
        dateOfBirth: new Date(2001, 4, 8),
        plan: "super-basic-plan"
    }
    $scope.data = userData;
});
app.filter("dashed", function(){
    /* this shall replace all dashes with space */
    return function(text){ 
        text.split("-").join(" "); 
    };
});
```

*Iam a newBie in Angular.js, so any help would be truly appreciated*

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a return statement in your filter function. The body of your filter function should look like:

```
return text.split("-").join(" ");
```

Here is a working example:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("userDataCtrl", function($scope) {
    var userData = {
      firstName: "Ashish",
      middleName: "",
      lastName: "Toppo",
      dateOfBirth: new Date(2001, 4, 8),
      plan: "super-basic-plan"
    }
    $scope.data = userData;
  })
  .filter("dashed", function() {
    /* this shall replace all dashes with space */
    return function(text) {
      // You were missing the following return
      return text.split("-").join(" ");
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="userDataCtrl">
    <strong>First Name:</strong> {{data.firstName}} <span>(this is not filtered)</span> <br>
    <strong>Last Name:</strong> {{data.lastName}} <span>(this is not filtered)</span> <br>

    <hr>

    <strong>First Name:</strong> {{data.firstName | uppercase}}
    <span>(this is filtered to uppercase)</span> <br>
    <strong>Last Name:</strong> {{data.lastName | lowercase}}
    <span>(this is filtered to lowercase)</span> <br>

    <hr>

    <strong>plan:</strong> {{data.plan | dashed}} <span>(this is custom filtered to Dashed)</span>
    <br>

  </div>
</div>
```

The filter must return a value. The screen was simply displaying the representation of `undefined`, which was the implicit return value.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I can say... Put filters before the controllers:

Same code, only filter before:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.filter("dashed", function(){
    return function(text){ 
        text.split("-").join(" "); 
    };
})
.controller("userDataCtrl", function($scope){
    var userData = {
        firstName: "Ashish",
        middleName: "",
        lastName: "Toppo",
        dateOfBirth: new Date(2001, 4, 8),
        plan: "super-basic-plan"
    }
    $scope.data = userData;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>learn angular</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="heading" id="heading"> {{"Hii"+" "+"There"}} </div>

    <!-- the below shall display the user data --> 
    <div ng-controller="userDataCtrl">
        <strong>First Name:</strong> {{data.firstName}} <span>(this is not filtered)</span> <br>
        <strong>Last Name:</strong> {{data.lastName}} <span>(this is not filtered)</span> <br>

        <hr>

        <strong>First Name:</strong> {{data.firstName | uppercase}}
        <span>(this is filtered to uppercase)</span> <br> 
        <strong>Last Name:</strong> {{data.lastName | lowercase}}
        <span>(this is filtered to lowercase)</span> <br>

        <hr>

        <strong>plan:</strong> {{data.plan | dashed}} <span>(this is custom filtered to Dashed)</span> 
        <br>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```